# Joining two Pandas DataFrames based on lat, long as fields

Tags: python, attribute-joins, latitude-longitude, pandas, data-frame

I have two Pandas DataFrames containing `"lat"` and `"long"` coordinates. I'd like to do a spatial join and merge columns from one `DataFrame` into another.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={
       'name': ['post', 'sutter', 'oak'],
       'Lat': [37.788151, 37.789551, 37.815730],
       'Long': [-122.407570, -122.408302, -122.288810]
      })


df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
       'id': [0, 1, 2],
       'col1': ['xx','yy','zz'],
       'Lat': [37.787994, 37.789575, 37.813122],
       'Long': [-122.407419, -122.408312, -122.288810]
      })
```

When a match is found based on the `"lat"`, `"long"` coordinates, the `join` / output would look like this:

```
name   Lat        Long         col1
post   37.788151  -122.407570  xx
sutter 37.789551  -122.408302  NaN
oak    37.815730  -122.288810  NaN
```

Open to ideas on how to implement this solution? Spatial joins or maybe using `reverse geocoding` API to get addresses from `"Lat"` `"Long"` and then join on them?

Comment: create a geodataframe using `points_from_xy`. create buffer for points (any one geodataframe) and [sjoin](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html#Joins)

Comment: I found the best (low error) way to do this was to reverse geocoding `Lat`, `Long` and join on address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Create Pandas DataFrame
2. Create GeoPandas DataFrame using #1
3. Create Buffer for Points
4. `sjoin` both GeoDataFrame

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
       'name': ['post', 'sutter', 'oak'],
       'Lat': [37.788151, 37.789551, 37.815730],
       'Long': [-122.407570, -122.408302, -122.288810]
      })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
       'id': [0, 1, 2],
       'col1': ['xx','yy','zz'],
       'Lat': [37.787994, 37.789575, 37.813122],
       'Long': [-122.407419, -122.408312, -122.288810]
      })
gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df1['Long'], df1['Lat']))

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2['Long'], df2['Lat']))

gdf2['geometry'] = gdf2.geometry.buffer(0.001)

gdf1.sjoin(gdf2, how="left")
```

Note that the join is completely dependent on your `buffer` size. Make sure to tune according to your needs.

Working copy can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Nczzio7tn4C7uVmbWgQt4EvWHnSOrAlc#scrollTo=8F1q51KfEXmL)

Comment: For the working space a person will need the Google account.

Comment: My `df1` contains 15M entries and has a size of 700MB. Just trying to perform `gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df1['Long'], df1['Lat']))` crashes my kernel. Any suggestions of some more memory efficient way to execute this task? tnx

Answer (score 5):

Another solution that was already mentioned by OP is to use the [reverse geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding). There might be a problem about that, the result quality will be strongly dependable on the decoder.

Here the [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/) geocoder (free to choose) from the GeoPy geocoding Python library was used, for more details, please check [the documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#nominatim). Also, coordinates of point features should be transmitted [as a pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770044/valueerror-must-be-a-coordinate-pair-or-point), otherwise, you may get this error `ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point`. Therefore `from geopy.point import Point` was additionally imported.

When using this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.point import Point

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="test")

def reverse_geocoding(lat, lon):
    try:
        location = geolocator.reverse(Point(lat, lon))
        return location.raw['place_id']
    except:
        return None

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={
       'name': ['post', 'sutter', 'oak'],
       'Lat': [37.788151, 37.789551, 37.815730],
       'Long': [-122.407570, -122.408302, -122.288810]
      })


df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
       'id': [0, 1, 2],
       'col1': ['xx','yy','zz'],
       'Lat': [37.787994, 37.789575, 37.813122],
       'Long': [-122.407419, -122.408312, -122.288810]
      })

df1['address'] = np.vectorize(reverse_geocoding)(df1['Lat'], df1['Long'])

df2['address'] = np.vectorize(reverse_geocoding)(df2['Lat'], df2['Long'])

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='address', right_on='address')

print(result)
```

it will result in this

```
     name      Lat_x      Long_x    address   id col1      Lat_y      Long_y
0    post  37.788151 -122.407570  127113751  NaN  NaN        NaN         NaN
1  sutter  37.789551 -122.408302  110481100  1.0   yy  37.789575 -122.408312
2     oak  37.815730 -122.288810  114898877  NaN  NaN        NaN         NaN
```

*Note:* the join was done by `"place_id"` attribute which is different to `"osm_id"`.

Comment: @Taras I am trying to implement this on my data, however, its taking too long to run. My dataframe is of 2000*80 shape.

Comment: Each of DataFrames is 2000*80 ?

Comment: What about yout solution with mapbox ? The same efficiency ?

Comment: For performance efficiency I am suggesting [asking a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)